# Does anyone know what the flame symbol means?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

[image]

I can’t figure out what the flame logo means. Can some please help?

Answer (score 1):

That's the Tinder app, apparently

Comment: I love the ambiguous use of the word "apparently" at the end of this answer. LOL. :)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket xD